# Find the number of different selections of two letters which can be made from the letters of the word PROBABILITY

Tags: probability

I study maths as a hobby. I am tackling this problem:

Find the number of different selections of two letters which can be made from the letters of the word PROBABILITY. how many of these selections do not contain a vowel?

I first of all isolated the unique letters PROBAILTY.

I then said for the first selection the number = $\binom{11}{2} = 55$

For the second selection the number = $\binom{9}{2} = 36$

Third selection = $\binom{7}{2} = 21$

and so on to get $\binom{11}{2} \cdot \binom{9}{2} \cdot \binom{7}{2} \cdot \binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{3}{2} = 55\times36\times21\times10\times3 = 1,247,400$

But now I am not sure of my working or how to proceed.

Comment: It looks like you're actually selecting five different pairs from a set of 11 different things. But the problem you're solving only wants how many selections of one pair ("selections of two letters"). Also your eleven things are not all different: there are two B's, two I's,and one each of the other 7 letters. That makes it a different way to count them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks how many distinct selections of two letters.

There are only two ways to select two letters with repetition and they are  $\{$BB$\}$ and $\{$II$\}$. Now there are $9$ distinct letters after taking out $1$ B and $1$ I and that gives us $9 \choose 2$ selections of two letters without repetition.

So in total, we have ${9 \choose 2} + 2 = 38$ selections of two letters.

Now if there are no vowels. We have $7$ letters with two B's. We have only one selection with repetition which is $\{$BB$\}$. Taking out $1$ B, we have $6$ distinct letters without vowels and that gives us ${6 \choose 2}$ selections of two letters without repetition.

So in total, we have ${6 \choose 2} + 1 = 16$ selections of two letters without a vowel.

Comment: Very clear. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Given that, we have to just 'select', this can be reduced to a simple combinations question.

Unique letters are $\text {{P, R, O, B, A, I, L, T, Y}}$

Therefore, the solution is simply $\binom{9}{2}=36$

Comment: But therre are e.g. two B's in the word PROBABILITY, so that one selection of 2 letters would be "BB" which in your approach was not counted.

Comment: @coffeemath You will have to add BB, II so 36 + 2 = 38. I don't think any other case is missing.

Comment: @Whyareyoureadingmyname I agree only two missing.

Comment: @coffeemath you are correct.  The book says 38